# Trouble getting blog categories in my array API

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this API for my wordpress blog.

{

```
  "count": 1,
  "totalPage": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "posts": [
    {
      "ID": 7809,
      "title": "Why Is It The Best Time To Buy In Perth?",
      "author": "Martin",
      "categories": [
        {
          "slug": "/buyers",
          "text": "Buyers"
        },
        {
          "slug": "/sellers",
          "text": "Sellers"
        }
      ],
      "content": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor"
    },
}
```

I can easily get the `title` by `echo $post['title']`, same with `author` by `echo $post['author']`. My problem is I cant get the value of the categories.

The output I'm expecting  is

```
<a href="/buyers">Buyers</a>
<a href="/sellers">Sellers</a>
```

This is what I've tried
`echo $post['categories']`, but the output is `ARRAY`

So then I've tried another one using foreach:

```
<?php  foreach ( $post['categories'] as $nameCategory) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $nameCategory->slug?>"><?php echo $nameCategory->text; ?></a>  
<?php } ?>
```

But no output is showing, its empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your case is in the variable type you are using to display the information. I am not sure how you are using `json_decode` in your PHP code, but if you are using `$post['title']` then your answer is converted to a PHP associative array.

So, when you are doing your foreach, instead of using `stdClass` you should be using the array like this:

```php
<?php  foreach ( $post['categories'] as $nameCategory) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $nameCategory['slug']?>"><?php echo $nameCategory['text']; ?></a>  
<?php } ?>
```

If you do a `print_r($post)` or `var_dump($post)` you should see the variable types you are using.

Also, when using an array as an object you should be getting an error message from PHP so you should check your php.ini configuration to see if your error messages are disabled or in its case are being saved to a log file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation, I will check that, and also your code is working fine. Thank you for your help solving this.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure as displayed seems to be JSON. But since you can get some values out of it, I will not bother about it. The reason you are not getting the right value is most likely wrong targeting. This particular set of data is nested inside another 'array' so to speak; simply reach it using the right name like:

```
echo $post['categories']['slug'];
echo $post['categories']['text'];
```